# Adding a suffix to names when storing results in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, paste, variable-names

I am making some plots in R in a for-loop and would like to store them using a name to describe the function being plotted, but also which data it came from.

So when I have a list of 2 data sets "x" and "y" and the loop has a structure like this:

```
x = matrix(
  c(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9),
  nrow=3,
  ncol=2)

y = matrix(
  c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180),
  nrow=3,
  ncol=2)

data <- list(x,y)

for (i in data){
  ??? <- boxplot(i)
}
```

I would like the `???` to be "name" + (i) + "_" separator. In this case the 2 plots would be called "plot_x" and "plot_y".

I tried some stuff with `paste("plot", names(i), sep = "_")` but I'm not sure if this is what to use, and where and how to use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

We can create an empty `list` with the `length` same as that of the 'data' and then store the corresponding output from the `for` loop by looping over the sequence of 'data'

```
out <- vector('list', length(data))    
for(i in seq_along(data)) {
      out[[i]] <- boxplot(data[[i]])
  }

str(out)
#List of 2
# $ :List of 6
#  ..$ stats: num [1:5, 1:2] 1 1.5 2 3 4 5 5.5 6 6.5 7
#  ..$ n    : num [1:2] 3 3
#  ..$ conf : num [1:2, 1:2] 0.632 3.368 5.088 6.912
#  ..$ out  : num(0) 
#  ..$ group: num(0) 
#  ..$ names: chr [1:2] "1" "2"
# $ :List of 6
#  ..$ stats: num [1:5, 1:2] 20 30 40 50 60 80 90 100 110 120
#  ..$ n    : num [1:2] 3 3
#  ..$ conf : num [1:2, 1:2] 21.8 58.2 81.8 118.2
#  ..$ group: num(0) 
#  ..$ names: chr [1:2] "1" "2"
```

If required, set the names of the `list` elements with the object names

```
names(out) <- paste0("plot_", c("x", "y"))
```

---

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment.  Instead as showed above, place the objects in a `list`

Answer (score 0):

akrun is right, you should try to avoid setting names in the global environment.  But if you really have to, you can try this,

```
> y = matrix(c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180),ncol=1)
> .GlobalEnv[[paste0("plot_","y")]] <- boxplot(y)
> str(plot_y)
List of 6
 $ stats: num [1:5, 1] 20 60 100 140 180
 $ n    : num 9
 $ conf : num [1:2, 1] 57.9 142.1
 $ out  : num(0)
 $ group: num(0)
 $ names: chr "1"
```

You can read up on `.GlobalEnv` by typing in `?.GlobalEnv`, into the R command prompt.